# find number in string, add 1 and replace

Tags: python, string, digit

I need to write a code where a string contains a number, then this number is incremented by 1, and then printed out within the initial string input.

It should work like this

```
>>>addNumber('I slept 3 hours')
what number would you like to increment? 3
I slept 4 hours
>>>addNumber('I have 366 friends on facebook')
what number would you like to increment? 6
I have 377 friends on facebook
```

so far I have this, but I know it is wrong and honestly I don't know how to do this.

```
def incrementNumbers(statement):
    number1=(int(input('What number would you like to increment?')))
    number2 = number1 +1
    i=[]
    for numbers in statement:
        if numbers.isdigit():
            i.append(numbers)
            statement.replace(numbers,number2)
```

Comment: What if they want to increment `9` in `399`?

Comment: I don't think it will be tested for 9, it says only single positive digits. So it would have to be from 0-8

Comment: 9 is both positive and single.

Comment: yes, but this is a very simple class, so I am just assuming we only need numbers from 0 to 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible error in your code is:

1. you are trying to replace with `int` type data in the `string` directly.
2. Also only checking `numbers.isdigit()` will modify all numbers irrespective of what you specified to modify.

Possible corrections to your code to make it run properly:

```
def incrementNumbers(statement):
    number1 = int(input('What number would you like to increment?'))
    number2 = number1 +1
    i=[]
    for numbers in statement:
        if numbers.isdigit() and int(numbers) == number1:
            i.append(numbers)
            statement.replace(numbers,str(number2))
```

You can also change your `incrementNumbers(statement)` function to:

```
def incrementNumbers(statement):
    number1 = input('What number would you like to increment?')
    number2 = str(int(number1)+1)
    statement = statement.replace(number1,number2)
    return statement
```

which I think is better than to use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.sub) here

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'I have 366 friends on facebook'
>>> def addone(obj):
...     val = int(obj.group(1))
...     return str(val+1)
... 
>>> i = raw_input('what number would you like to increment?')
what number would you like to increment?6
>>> re.sub('({})'.format(i),addone,s)
'I have 377 friends on facebook'
```

Another Example

```
>>> s = 'I slept 3 hours'
>>> i = raw_input('what number would you like to increment?')
what number would you like to increment?3
>>> re.sub('({})'.format(i),addone,s)
'I slept 4 hours'
```

And you can define your function like

```
def addNumber(s):
    def addone(obj):
        val = int(obj.group(1))
        return str(val+1)

    i = raw_input('what number would you like to increment?')
    return(re.sub('({})'.format(i),addone,s))
```

However I advice that you have a validation function

```
i = raw_input('what number would you like to increment?')
if 0<int(i)<9:
    return(re.sub('({})'.format(i),addone,s))
else:
    return "Number out of range"
```

This will prevent the user from entering values outside your range

Answer (score 0):

Under your requirements that the numeric value must be between 0 and 8, you can use [`string.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html)

```
def increment(s, inc):
    return s.replace(str(inc), str(inc + 1))

>>> s = 'I have 366 friends on facebook'
>>> inc = 6
>>> increment(s, 6)
'I have 377 friends on facebook'
```