# multiply a digit inside list as string

Tags: python, list

I have been trying to figure out if there is a way to do this

```
import re
myList = ["a6C"] >>> ["a12C"]

updatedLst=[]


for indx,item in enumerate(myList):
    val=(re.findall('\d+', item))
    myList[indx]=val

print(myList)
```

1 way I can do this is by hard coding the value like this
if "6" in item:

I want to do it in a different way. I understand there is no reason to use such a mixed list or bad design... I just want to find out the "way"/logic to solve this. Thanks for your ideas and time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30717634/find-number-in-string-add-1-and-replace

Comment: hmm it works for a single digit only there but the `re.sub` is the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, use:

```
import re
myList = ["a6C"]
for indx, item in enumerate(myList):
    myList[indx] = ''.join([str(int(i)*2) if i.isdigit() else i for i in item])
print(myList)
```

Or:

```
import re
myList = ["a6C"]
for indx, item in enumerate(myList):
    myList[indx] = re.sub('\d+',str(int(re.sub('\D+','',item))*2),item)
print(myList)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a  version which is not very efficient.

```
import re
strng="ro5e"

#the following variable finds numeric value and saves in variable num
num=re.findall('\d+',strng)

#for item in strng: will not find numeric value because everything will be String there
#Hence the following approach,iterate num
for i in num:
     v=int(i)*2 #using int to convert String to int so that I can multiply
     print(strng.replace(i,str(v)))#again converting to str so that I can replace
```